# A simple cURL request

Tags: curl

Forgive me if its too basic but i am programming in other languages .
So i have the `Parse.com` API , and i am sending requests successfully with :

```
  $url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/USERS';  
    $headers = array(  
   "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
 );  
 $rest = curl_init();  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_GET,1);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
 curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
 $response = curl_exec($rest);  
 $json = json_decode($response, true);
```

Then i wanted to add some constrains to it, so according to their API to add a constrain you do :

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: YYYYYYYYYYYYYY" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/USERS
```

So, i am trying to understand how do i put this `"where"` field into my existing request that i showed above ? (what the -G means here? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the cURL manual:

> **-G, --get**
>
> When  used,  this  option  will  make  all data specified with -d,
>   --data, --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The
>   data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.
>
> If used in combination with -I, the POST data will instead be appended
>   to the URL with a HEAD request.
>
> If this option is used several times, only the first one is used. This
>   is because undoing a GET doesn't make sense, but you should then
>   instead enforce the alternative method you prefer

So the PHP equivalent would be:

```
$params = 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}';
$url    = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/USERS?' . urlencode($params);
```